# Higher precendence operator doesn't get evaluated first in while condition's expression

Tags: java, while-loop, operators

Take a look at the following code:

```
class experiment{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 3;

        while (k-- > 0) {
            System.out.println(k + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
2
1
```

Actual output:

```
2
1
0
```

Postfix operators have higher precedence than operational operators. Hence `k--` should be evaluated first before the `k > 0`, but looking at the output, `k > 0` gets evaluated first. Do I miss something simple here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precedence has nothing to do with it. The value of 'k--' is 'k'. There is a *side-effect* of post-decrementing 'k' but it doesn't affect the operand value.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you are right. `k--` will be evaluated first. But it is really evaluated to `k`. And after the current operation involving it is completed, it's value is increased. So, first the current value is used and then the increment happen.

Had you used `--k`, you would have got the expected output.

Just try these examples, you will understand: -

```
int k = 4;
System.out.println(k-- + " : " + k);  // prints 4 : 3

int x = 5;
System.out.println(--x + " : " + x);  // prints 4 : 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the `k--` is evaluated before the `> 0`. However, the result of that evaluation is `k`, not `k - 1`, as the `--` is post-fix, not pre-fix.

So, the first time the `>` is evaluated, it is effectively `3 > 0`, because although `k` now is `2`, the result of the *expression* `k--` is `3`. By the time the print comes around though, `k = 2`, hence `2` is output first. This is why you get one more iteration than (I guess) you were expecting.